# Google analytic device types aggregated over several pages matching a regex

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have several pages on my website and I'm interested in the distribution of device types only for some specific pages of my messaging systems (mobile VS tablet VS desktop).

I'd like to have an aggregated view of the device types only pages matching the regex ^/conversations/* (the * should ideally be a regex matching only document IDs like `/conversations/5e4cf324fab3582bfe87ee2d`)

The closest I'm able to get is something like this

[image: Example of filtering]

But I would need to 
  - only match the /conversations/[ID] URLs (that is, exclude the root, exclude sub-urls like /new, etc); I can probably figure this out on my own)
  - Group+count them by device type (I would like to see only 3 lines with the total % of mobile VS tablet VS desktop)

Is this something I could do directly in the Analytics GUI, or do I need to retrieve those results and perform the reduce operation with code ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
^\/conversations\/.
```

Comment: The problem is that I already have URLs like `/conversations/new` that would be caught by your regex